# How do I make Texts in multiple row and columns in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How do I achieve Row and Column Grid Text Alignment in Flutter? Check the example down below :

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use **Table** and **TableRow** in order to achieve the design that you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Wrap` widget

```dart
Wrap(
children:[],
)
```

Make width of the each widget in children to half of the total width

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Warp. use this structure:

`Wrap(children:[])`